# Rails Route? How To Rename URL in Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I would like to rename my categories URL from https://website.com/categories/apples (#1) to

https://website.com/hi-apples-bye (#2)

I am trying to accomplish two things:

Display the #2 URL in the SITEMAP and PATH

Routes:

```
resources :categories

get '/hi-:id-bye', to: "categories#show"
```

However, I get URL https://website.com/categories/apples in the sitemap and https://website.com/hi-apples-bye for the path.

Any help would be appreciated! I am a rookie...

Comment: You haven't disabled the `GET /categories/:id` resource yet. To do so remove the show action from `resources :categories` by adding the `except: :show` option.

Comment: Guess, hi-:id-bye is like a title of the categories? In this case there is a gem called slug which will change all your id's to title in the url

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you need all category resource routes to have the same route prefix but for the example you have given you could just have:

```
resources :categories # this is to keep the existing REST routes

# outside categories do ... end
get '/hi-:id-bye', to: "categories#show" # this is to add the route you want
```

See this section for more details: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#non-resourceful-routes